# How to train ML model with multiple variables?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn Machine Learning concepts these days. I understand in a traditional ML data, we will have *features* and *labels*. I have following toy data in my mind where I have features like 'units_sold' and 'num_employees' and a label of 'cost_$'. I would like to train the model to learn these features and label for a particular 'city' and 'store'. For example if I perform Linear Regression, the model learn intercept and coefficient for the city and store it relates to. When I input units_sold and num_employees for next year, I get the prediction.

```
city        store   units_sold  num_employees   cost_$
New York    A       10          4               11000
New York    B       12          4               11890
New York    C       14          5               15260
New York    D       17          6               17340
London      A       23          5               22770
London      B       27          6               25650
London      C       22          3               21450
Paris       A       4           2               5200
Paris       B       7           3               9590
```

I'm trying to brainstorm about it and would like to know how to approach this problem?

Comment: You can either build say 3 separate models (or 9, if you want all 9 permutations of city vs store), but the more conventional way might be one hot coding your string based features into numeric value into 1 model. You just supply the encoded city and store along with your units_sold and num_employees as part of the input to get your prediction.

Comment: @TheLyrist Great suggestion and I can use sklearn to do LabelEncoding. So it means model will also learn coeff and intercept for these labels?

Comment: Yes. the model will take care of these values during prediction.

Comment: So you want to be able to give a city, store, units sold, employees and predict the  cost. Is that correct?

Comment: @JahKnows Yes thats correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very little data so doing much with it is very difficult. especially considering you expect to get 'next year' estimates without having any historical data to base yourself from.

However, if you want to be able to estimate a cost given your input features which are city, store, units_sold and num_employees then this problem setup is very standard in machine learning.

First I will put your data into a pandas DataFrame and I will encode your categorical features using numerical values. I did this randomly, but I think you can get better results by getting the latitude and longitude of the stores, as well as some data about the neighborhood (density, wealth, etc.).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'city': ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'London', 'London', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
        'store': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
        'units_sold': [10, 12, 14, 17, 23, 27, 22, 4, 7],
        'num_employees': [4,4,5,6,5,6,3,2,3],
        'cost': [11000, 11890, 15260, 17340, 22770, 25650, 21450, 5200, 9560]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['store'] =df['store'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['city'] =df['city'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

When I am working with very little data I always like to pull some visualizations to give me some intuition about the data. Let's first see how the features are correlated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.matshow(df.corr())
plt.xticks(np.arange(5), df.columns, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(5), df.columns, rotation=0)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can see that the cost is associated directly with units_sold. That is not much of a surprise I guess. But it also correlates with the num_employees and is strongly inversely correlated with the city.

If we plot the num_employees and units_sold we can see that the correlations observed above more clearly.

[image]

## A predictive model

Now we want to be able to give a model our inputs and get an estimation of the cost.

Let's first put our data into a training and testing set. This is very problematic with such a small dataset because you have a very high probability of ending up with a training set that omits a city, or a store type. This will significantly affect the abiltiy of the model to predict an output for data it has never seen.

The labels of the data are the cost.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.asarray(df[['city', 'num_employees', 'store', 'units_sold']])
Y = np.asarray(df['cost'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)
```

Let's start with a standard linear regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lineReg = LinearRegression()
lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score: ', lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
print('Weights: ', lineReg.coef_)

plt.plot(lineReg.predict(X_test))
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.show()
```

> Score:  0.963554136721 
>   Weights:  [ 506.87136393  -15.48157725  376.79379444  920.01939237]

[image]

A better alternative is to use ridge regression.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score: ', reg.score(X_test, y_test))
print('Weights: ', reg.coef_)

plt.plot(reg.predict(X_test))
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.show()
```

> Score:  0.971197683706 
> Weights:  [ 129.78467277    2.034588
>   97.11724313  877.73906409]

[image]

If you do another split and rerun both these models you will see that the performance varies greatly for both of them as we expected due to the limited data. However, the effect is much more pronounced for the simple linear regression.

To get a better idea of the actual results, let's do something a bit naughty. We will split the data over and over again to get different models and get the average of their scores.

```
scores = []
coefs = []
for i in range(1000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)
    lineReg = LinearRegression()
    lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    scores.append(lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
    coefs.append(lineReg.coef_)
print('Linear Regression')
print(np.mean(scores))
print(np.mean(coefs, axis=0))

scores = []
coefs = []
for i in range(1000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)
    lineReg = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
    lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    scores.append(lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
    coefs.append(lineReg.coef_)
print('\nRidge Regression')
print(np.mean(scores))
print(np.mean(coefs, axis=0))
```

> Linear Regression 
>   -1.43683760609 
>   [ 1284.47358731  1251.8762943   -706.31897708   846.5465552 ] 
>   
>   Ridge Regression 
>   0.900877146134 
>   [ 228.05312491   95.33306385  123.49517018  873.49803782]

We can see that across 1000 trials the ridge regression was by far the superior model.

Now you can use this model to estimate costs by passing the model a vector with the features in the same order as the dataset as follows

```
reg.predict([[2,  4,  1,  12]])
```

The resulting score is

> array([ 12853.2132658])

---

This is not enough data to do any machine learning regression reliably. However you can get some insight into what factors affect your cost the most.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for putting time & effort into this. It has given me a good direction. The data was not real but I just made up in excel for some real-world problem I would like to solve. Awesome work there.

Answer (score 0):

You mention Linear Regression specifically. For this we can use a tool like PySpark VectorAssembler to create a vector out of several columns.

For example, for several columns CRIM,ZN,INDUS,etc that you want to pass to Linear regression, you can create a new dataframe like below.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PT', 'B', 'LSTAT'], outputCol = 'features')
vhouse_df = vectorAssembler.transform(house_df)
vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select(['features', 'label'])
vhouse_df.show(3)
```